# Display flash message with model validations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, flash-message

I have the following model validations...

```
  validates :event_id, :uniqueness => {:scope => :email}
  validates_format_of :email, :with => /\A[^@]+@([^@\.]+\.)+[^@\.]+\z/
  validates_presence_of :email, :first_name, :last_name
```

..and here is my controller...

```
def register_learner
    @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
    begin
      EventRegistration.create! first_name: params[:first_name], last_name: params[:last_name], email: params[:email], event_id: params[:event_id]
      rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid => e
    end
end
```

This codes work, but the problems is it silently catches the errors. I'd like to display a flash message to the user and in the current page. So I tried this...

```
   def register_learner
    @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
    begin
      @registation = EventRegistration.create! first_name: params[:first_name], last_name: params[:last_name], email: params[:email], event_id: params[:event_id]
      rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid => e
      if !@registation.valid?
        flash[:notice] = @registation.errors
      end
    end
   end
```

...but I get the message `` undefined method `valid?' for nil:NilClass `` if the validation fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `new` instead of `create!` you will end up with an instance that can tell you `valid? == false`.

You also won't need the rescue in this case.

So you could do something like this:

```
def register_learner
  @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
  @registation = EventRegistration.new(
    first_name: params[:first_name], 
    last_name: params[:last_name], 
    email: params[:email], 
    event_id: params[:event_id]
  )
  flash[:notice] = @registation.errors unless @registation.valid?
end
```

Also, if you might already have an existing registration, you could use `find_or_initialize_by` and then check if the resulting object is a new record with `@registration.new_record?`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks chad_. That was the ticket. For a complete solution here is what I did...

```
def register_learner
    @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
    @registation = EventRegistration.new first_name: params[:first_name], last_name: params[:last_name], email: params[:email], event_id: params[:event_id]
    if !@registation.valid?
      flash[:notice] = @registation.errors.full_messages.to_sentence
      redirect_to(event_path(@event))
    else
      @registation.save
    end
end
```

Comment: No problem.  You missed an `end`. ;)